# как передать объект класса в конструктор другого класса

Tags: flutter, dart

как передать объект класса  в конструктор другого класса из другого файла. Например есть файл с классом А и его конструктором. И есть другой файл с стэйтлесс виджетом в который и нужно передать конструктор класса А.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo {
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "Может быть я плохо понял вопрос?" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(Foo foo): _foo(foo) {};
    void print() {
        _foo.print();
    }
private:
    Foo _foo;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar(foo);
    bar.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Этот ответ точно соответствует вопросу? Судя по тегу, вопрос относиться к языку dart, а не c++

Comment: Я думал это dart. Нет не соответствует тогда.